# Stuck on minifyReleaseWithR8 after upgrading to Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2 from 7.3.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-r8

This is the last output I get when I run the release build of my Android app with `--info`:

```
.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.ktor\ktor-client-core-jvm\1.5.4\81e8f8bb9622b96661c739ca18146e4079191c20\ktor-client-core-jvm-1.5.4.jar: R8: Invalid signature '(TTBuilder;)V' for method void io.ktor.client.HttpClientConfig$install$1.invoke(java.lang.Object).
Validation error: A type variable is not in scope.
Signature is ignored and will not be present in the output.

AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #0: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #1: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #2: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #3: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #4: shutdown
AAPT2 aapt2-7.4.2-8841542-windows Daemon #5: shutdown
```

Comment: By "Gradle 7.4.2" do you mean "Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2"? If so have you tried version 8.0.2, which is the latest stable? If you still see this issue, please open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788. If possible with a reproduction, which can be in form of a dump (https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/main/doc/compilerdump.md#generating-a-dump-with-gradle-and-the-android-studio-plugin).

Comment: @sgjesse Yes, AGP, updated the title now. The issue persists, tested with 8.1.0. Opened an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295509069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the R8 team. The issue is gone when I add this to settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url = uri("https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw")
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("com.android.tools:r8:4.0.67")
        }
    }
}
```

See this link for more info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295509069